# How to display form value in the address bar or pass it on the another page using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently stuck at this form. What I am trying to do is enter the name and email from the form and redirect the values on the another page but the values should be show in the address bar
on the next page and the point is this should be done only with in JavaScript.

**Here is the form look:**
[can see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGTf9.png)

**code for this form:**

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" target="_blank" >
 <div style="display: none;">
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="366827005" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlist4823096" />
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?name=<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name_(awf_first)")</script>" id="redirect_4acabdbbe3825a3800648e3cae5fa1c6" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_redirect_onlist" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?email=<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="My_Web_Form_2" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
 </div>


 <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-96089735">Name: </label>
 <div class="af-textWrap">
 <input id="awf_field-96089735" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="500" />
 </div>

 <div class="af-clear"></div></div>
 <div class="af-element">
 <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-96089736">Email: </label>
 <div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-96089736" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " />
 </div><div class="af-clear"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="af-element buttonContainer">
 <input name="submit" id="af-submit-image-366827005" type="image" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" alt="Submit Form" src="https://forms.aweber.com/images/forms/big-sale/blue/circle-submit-button.png" tabindex="502" />
 </form>
```

Now, when I enter the values in Name and email fields and hit the submit button I will redirect to the next page.

**Address bar of next page:[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laaDl.jpg)**

As you can see in this above link ***https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?name=***

The javascript wasn’t work. you can check the coding in the form code above.

What I want is if I enter name=navjot in form then url bar will be contain **https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?name=navjot**
I know its a simple but I don’t know how to do in javascript any help is apprecheated
any help or example would help me.

Comment: you have not shared the javascript

Comment: sir I don't know much js but as you can see in the form code there is a input tag under the value i post there a js code

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?name=<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name_(awf_first)")</script>" id="redirect_4acabdbbe3825a3800648e3cae5fa1c6" />
     <input type="hidden" name="meta_redirect_onlist" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?email=<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>" /> here it is you can see it under the form code..

Comment: I suggest dont use double quotes for `formData.display("name_(awf_first)")`. Instead of it use single quote. And the same for `formData.display("email")`

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a script tag to the `location.href`? Rather pass the data only, not the script itself.

Comment: can you give me an example of location.href?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location Also, you have to fix the quoting.

Comment: i try but still the same result  Spidercode

Comment: i try everything change the quoting but still  in the addressbar same result

Comment: https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?name=<script%20type=    this is what i get on the another page

Comment: **You can not** use `<script>` tags inside `<someTag value="HERE"` your first need to fix your HTML before adding javascript.

Comment: its getting up the hole type code  in value tag instead of a entered data

Comment: caramba so where is the problem? how can i pass the values then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of suggestions here:

1. Use single and double quotation marks properly
2. Do not write scripts inside your DOM elements
3. Do not use inline style. Instead of that use CSS.
4. Use appropriate elements based on their
   functionality. For example: For `button` use input type as a
   `button` or `submit` and add image to that button by using css

Considering the fact that id of the textbox `awf_field-96089735` is not auto generated.

Create a javascript method called `HandleSubmit` as shown below:

```
<script>
    function HandleSubmit() {
        var baseUrl = "https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?";
        baseUrl += "name=" + document.getElementById("awf_field-96089735").value;

        window.location.href = baseUrl; 
    }
 </script>
```

And add `onclick` event to your image and call HandleSubmit() as shown below:

```
<input onclick="HandleSubmit()" name="submit" id="af-submit-image-366827005" type="image" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" alt="Submit Form" src="https://forms.aweber.com/images/forms/big-sale/blue/circle-submit-button.png" tabindex="502" />
```

So your final code would look like:

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" target="_blank" >
 <div style="display: none;">
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="366827005" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlist4823096" />
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?name=<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("name_(awf_first)")</script>" id="redirect_4acabdbbe3825a3800648e3cae5fa1c6" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_redirect_onlist" value="https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?email=<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="My_Web_Form_2" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />
 <input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
 </div>


 <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-96089735">Name: </label>
 <div class="af-textWrap">
 <input id="awf_field-96089735" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="500" />
 </div>

 <div class="af-clear"></div></div>
 <div class="af-element">
 <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-96089736">Email: </label>
 <div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-96089736" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501" onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " />
 </div><div class="af-clear"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="af-element buttonContainer">
 <input onclick="HandleSubmit()" name="submit" id="af-submit-image-366827005" type="image" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" alt="Submit Form" src="https://forms.aweber.com/images/forms/big-sale/blue/circle-submit-button.png" tabindex="502" />
 </form>

 <script>
    function HandleSubmit() {
        var baseUrl = "https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?";
        baseUrl += "name=" + document.getElementById("awf_field-96089735").value;

        window.location.href = baseUrl; 
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: thankyou , spidercode for writing this code for me i really apprecheated this  you are going right but now i got https://wanderistlife.typeform.com/to/u52pwv?name=[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: i need the name instead of [object HTMLInputElement] which i enter from the form. sorry for hurdle but i really don't know the js

Comment: My bad. Updated code. Use `document.getElementById("awf_field-96089735").value`. Please upvote and mark it as an answer if that helps.

Comment: you help me in the bad situation sir i m very thankful to you... wish you god bless sir.

Comment: happy to help you